# How do I get the new async semantics working in VS2017 RC?

Tags: c#, async-await, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

Quoting from [Visual Studio 2017 RC Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#a-idcshappvb-ac-and-visual-basic)

> **Language Extensions and Analyzers**
>
> This release includes some proposed new language extensions that we are working on for the next versions of C# and Visual Basic. These new language features are enabled by default and include:
>
> For C#:
>
> - [Task-like return types for async methods](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7169): This introduces the ability to return any task-like type from an async method. Previously these return types were constrained to `Task<T>` and `Task`.

It says it's enabled by default, but I'm not able to get this to work. Even taking the exact ArbitraryAsyncReturns.zip download from the linked Github page (and fixing up the references to React NuGet packages to remove unrelated errors), but without installing the custom VSIX package (which is for VS2015), I continue to get

> error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>

Do I need to take any additional steps to get this working?

---

I first tried reducing that specific example to a minimal version that should work, but trying to play with it, I didn't know yet what should work and what shouldn't. At the very least though, given this language enhancement, I expected a bogus program such as

```
struct Test { }
static class Program {
    static async Test Test() { }
    static void Main() { }
}
```

to fail to compile with a different error message. Getting the same error message even then suggested that this language extension was not yet enabled, but JaredPar noticed that the error message simply hasn't been updated yet.

---

I now reduced one of the supposedly valid examples to a minimal version that I think should compile (but fail at run-time due to the unimplemented methods), but doesn't compile:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
    public class TasklikeAttribute : Attribute {
        public TasklikeAttribute(Type builderType) { }
    }
}

struct TasklikeTypeMethodBuilder<T> {
    public static TasklikeTypeMethodBuilder<T> Create() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void SetResult(T result) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void SetException(Exception exception) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public TasklikeType<T> Task => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

[Tasklike(typeof(TasklikeTypeMethodBuilder<>))]
struct TasklikeType<T> { }

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) { }
    static async TasklikeType<string> TasklikeTypeTester() {
        await Task.Yield();
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The same compiler error as above is generated for `static async TasklikeType<string> TasklikeTypeTester()`.

Comment: What's your understanding of what a **Task-like type** is? Have you read the referenced GitHub Issue?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Of course. I did not think my `Test` struct was a task-like type. I specifically pointed out that I did not expect that code to compile, I merely expected the error message to be different, to refer to task-like types rather than `Task`. And I also tried the supposedly valid code *from* the Github issue, which fails to compile as well. But: a task-like type is a type with the `Tasklike` attribute applied to it (which may be user-defined), where that attribute specifies a builder type. What the types do is not really the compiler's problem, and some examples are hardly task-like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TasklikeAttribute` attribute name turns out isn't what's implemented in VS2017 RC, that's from a different version of the proposal. What's actually implemented relies on a type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute`, which appears to work exactly the same way.

I was not able to find this documented, but I was able to find this in the Roslyn tests, for example [CodeGenAsyncTests.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Emit/CodeGen/CodeGenAsyncTests.cs):

> ```
> [AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(ValueTaskMethodBuilder))]
> struct ValueTask { }
> ...
> namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices { class AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute : System.Attribute { public AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute(System.Type t) { } } }
> ```

Comment: `[AsyncMethodBuilder]` is a lot less pretty than `[Tasklike]` :(

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing else you need to do to enable task-like returns.  The issue here is that the diagonstic message for this feature hasn't been updated yet.  Here is a link to the tracking issue:

> https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12621

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that, that answers a part of it. The supposedly valid code I linked to in my question fails as well though. When I can, I'll try to update my question with a minimal program I *think* should be valid.

Comment: Well, it turns out you were right that there's nothing to do to enable task-like returns. However, the proposal that MS links to isn't exactly what got implemented... That was pointlessly confusing.

Comment: As @hvd says, that answers a part of it, But although there's nothing to do  to enable task-like returns, I can't even find "ValueTask" out of the box in VS 2017 RC, and I don't know if I have to download and install the ArbirtraryAsynReturns.zip and the VSIX packages to get it.

Comment: @SERWare That would be a .NET Framework addition, not a compiler addition, so cannot be supplied as part of VS2017. When you use the type, and you get the red line indicating it cannot be found, VS2017 already tells you that it's part of Microsoft's [`System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/) NuGet package and offers to install it.

Comment: @hvd thank you very much, I'll try it after work today in a project targeting NET Framework 4.6.2 (I think that I only noticed the error message, not noticed the red line).