# If it's possible to write our own awaitables, then why can async methods only return Task<T>, Task and void?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking at the MSDN documentation and it says

> Async methods have three possible return types: `Task<TResult>`, `Task`,
>   and `void`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674893.aspx

However, I remember reading somewhere else that it's possible to write to `await` custom awaiters. How can I reconcile these 2 facts?

Comment: What kind of async method do you want to write which need another return type?

Comment: An async method (as consumed by the compiler) must return those types. The same reason why a generator method must return `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` for the compiler to create the generator. It says nothing about handwritten awaiters. You just have to implement the appropriate interface.

Comment: Note: in VS2017RC, `async` methods can return other types too.

Comment: Are you sure, @hvd?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yes, I am sure. The error message has not yet been updated, so if you try an invalid type you get a misleading message, but look for `ValueTask` on NuGet.

Comment: @hvd, can you give me the links? For the NuGet package and compiler documentation?

Comment: @PauloMorgado For the NuGet Package, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/. For documentation, that's not yet ready. See Stephen Cleary's answer for a link to the initial proposal, but it's not exactly what VS2017RC implements, that uses a different attribute name (my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133510/how-do-i-get-the-new-async-semantics-working-in-vs2017-rc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` supports any kind of "awaitable", which are object instances that follow a certain pattern (`GetAwaiter`, etc).

`async` generates a state machine which only knows how to create `Task`/`Task<T>` awaitables (or return `void`).

So, you can create your own custom awaitable object and return that, but you have to do it explicitly. You can't use `async` to do it.

The compiler team is currently looking at [adding `ValueTask` support to `async`](https://github.com/ljw1004/roslyn/blob/features/async-return/docs/specs/feature%20-%20arbitrary%20async%20returns.md). This would allow you to use "async method builders" that would follow a pattern. Then you'd be able to use `async` as well as `await` to operate on *any* kind of "tasklike" type. Unfortunately, it would still not allow `async` methods to return interface types, though - changes in other parts of the language are necessary for that.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it would still not allow async methods to return interface types, though" -- Are you sure? The version that's implemented in VS2017RC should allow that, as it no longer requires a static method on the type, just an attribute. Will test when I get home.

Comment: I've tested it now, and VS2017RC allows async methods to return interface types the same as any other custom type, so long as the correct async method builder is provided.

Comment: @hvd That's excellent news! I wasn't aware they had changed that.

Answer (score 2):

The native classes shipped with .NET (specifically TaskAwaiter) only support `Task`, `Task<T>` and `void` as awaitable, thus this is all MSDN tells you about. However, you can write custom awaiters that allow awaiting other types.

According to https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern, an object is awaitable if:

> - It has a GetAwaiter() method (instance method or extension method);
> - Its GetAwaiter() method returns an awaiter. An object is an awaiter if:
>
>   - It implements INotifyCompletion or ICriticalNotifyCompletion interface;
>   - It has an IsCompleted, which has a getter and returns a Boolean;
>   - it has a GetResult() method, which returns void, or a result.

Comment: So MSDN is lying?

Comment: @user7127000 It's not lying, nowhere does it say that you *can't* make your own awaitable classes. It would be nice if they had an example or a link to an article explaining that you can, but nothing on that page is incorrect with regards to the native .NET classes, and you can't very well expect MSDN to document your custom code.

Comment: @user7127000 Of note, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx does say that "The task to which the await operator is applied typically is the return value from a call to a method that implements the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern. Examples include values of type Task or Task<TResult>." It doesn't say that Task or Task<TResult> are the only types, only that they are examples of awaitable types.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the link you provided reads as follows:

> Updated: July 20, 2015

So this is a bit dated. With that said, originally `async` methods did only have `Task<TResult>`, `Task`, and `void` as valid returns types. According to the **C# Language Specification** the following is stated:

**10.15 Async Functions**

> The return-type of an async method must be either void or a task type.

With the introduction of **UWP**, you get four more built-in types:

1. [`IAsyncAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncaction.aspx)
2. [`IAsyncActionWithProgress<TProgress>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206581.aspx)
3. [`IAsyncOperation<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx)
4. [`IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult, TProgress>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206594.aspx)

These are considered "async types" and you are allowed to use the `async` and `await` keywords on them as you'd expect.

More from the spec:

> The *return-type* of an async method must be either void or a ***task type***.
>   The task types are `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and types constructed
>   from `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>`. For the sake of brevity, in this
>   chapter these types are referenced as `Task` and `Task<T>`, respectively.
>   An async method returning a task type is said to be task-returning.
>
> The exact definition of the task types is implementation defined, but
>   from the language’s point of view a task type is in one of the states
>   incomplete, succeeded or faulted. A faulted task records a pertinent
>   exception. A succeeded `Task<T>` records a result of type `T`. Task types
>   are awaitable, and can therefore be the operands of await expressions

Comment: You've always been able to `await` any type following a given pattern.  That's different than having an `async` method that can return any arbitrary type.  The state machine generated by `async` only creates tasks, which is very different.