# Implementing global operation result in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, operator-overloading

To describe the result of any business operation,
I have the following `Result` class

```cs
public class Result<TResponse>
{
    public TResponse? Response { get; set; }
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; }

    internal Result(TResponse response, Exception exception)
    {
        Response = response;
        Exception = exception;
    }

    public static implicit operator Result<TResponse>(TResponse response)
    {
        return new Result<TResponse>(response, default);
    }

    public static implicit operator Result<TResponse>(Exception e)
    {
        return new Result<TResponse>(default, e);
    }
  
    //TODO other codes that I want to ask 
}
```

It overloaded operators for TResponse and Exception 
So I can use the following code happily:

```cs
    public Result<int> Method1()
    {
        try
        {
            //do_some_sync_stuff()
            return 42;//will return Result<int>(42,null)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;//will return Result<int>(null,e)
        }
    }
```

Now I want to use async version of the latest code like that:

```cs
    public async Result<int> Method2()
    {
        try
        {
            //await do_some_async_stuff()
            return 42;//example value
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

But dotnet gets angry and says:

```
error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T>
```

Is there a way to achive that ? 
I know I can use `Task<Result<int>>` but it is way more complicated to use like that- nested generics
I have tried to add GetAwaiter and implement AsyncMethodBuilder but can't success -returning exceptions do not work

Related links but not solving exactly that issue:
[link1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/extending-the-async-methods-in-c/) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133510/how-do-i-get-the-new-async-semantics-working-in-vs2017-rc) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721979/in-c7-how-can-i-roll-my-own-task-like-type-to-use-with-async)

Comment: *but it is way more complicated to use like that* - soo.. are you asking for advice on how to make your `Result<T>` awaitable?

Comment: I want my class Result<T> awaitable and also have operator overloaded to Exceptions, so I can return both T and Exception instances

Comment: Is that not rather bizarre though, when you consider that there is already a mechanism that can return T results, and is awaitable, and can collect exceptions?

Comment: Maybe, But I think the latest usage is very clear you just write return t; or return e;

Comment: `public async Task<Result<int>> Method2() { ... return await Task.FromResult(42);}`?

Comment: @Jimi  My current codebase is all like you mentioned but I usually need List<SomeDTO> rather than int, that causes Task<Result<List<SomeDTO>>> -- strange huh ?

Comment: When you await `Method2()`, you get `Result<List<SomeDTO>>` as return value, so `Response` is a `List<SomeDTO>` and null Exception. Isn't that expected? What kind of result do you want instead?

Comment: That is absolutely true, we don't have anything to do with that, I just want to use both return 42(data); and return exception; in a single async method returning async Result<T>

Comment: Assuming that you'll find a solution to compile-error problem, how do you intend to use the `Method2` method? Do you intend to use it with await like this? `Result<int> result = await Method2();` What if the caller doesn't `await` immediately the method, and instead store the return value into a variable? `var x = Method2();` What will be the type of `x`?

Comment: *I think the latest usage is very clear you just write return t; or return e;* - or equally, if your method returned a Task<T> you could also return t, and not need to return e because there is the throwing mechanism instead! Even more clear, and beats then having to put an if after every operation to check if it succeeded or not..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a async processing in your method you need to have a return type like **Task**. Because the compiler its doing a cast like

```
Result<int> = Task<Result<int>>
```

because of the async method.

If you add the Task return type, the cast should work fine.